# Validate SA Vat number in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to validate SA VAT Number in HTML5 and JavaScript

I use the following to validate

HTML CODE

```
<label>VAT Number :</label></br>
            <div class="warn"><span id="statusVatnumber"></span></div>
            <input type="hidden" id="vatnumber" class="hiddenId value=" Value="" />
           <input type="text" name="vatnumber" id="vatnumber" onkeyup="validate_vatnumber(this);" placeholder="VAT Number"  title="Please provide a valid company VAT number" <?php getpostvalue('vatnumber');?>/></br>          
           <p> </br>
```

JavaScript

```
function validate_vatnumber(vatnumber) {        
  var regVatnumber = /[0-9]{9}/;
  if(regVatnumber.test(vatnumber) == false) {
    document.getElementById("statusVatnumber").innerHTML = "Vat Number is not valid"        
  } else {
    document.getElementById("statusVatnumber").innerHTML = "You have entered a valid Vat Number!";
  } 
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are having?

Comment: Use regex as `/^[0-9]{9}$/`. Also add same on input. `<input type="number" maxlength="9" />` or `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{9}" />`

Comment: I tried to use what you suggested, but m still getting the same error.

Comment: Why did you rollback the edit? Now your code is unreadable again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to validate the input element itself:

```
 onkeyup="validate_vatnumber(this);"
```

when you want to validate its *value*. Either pass the value in:

```
onkeyup="validate_vatnumber(this.value);"
```

or just pass `this`, and pull the value out in your script:

```
function validate_vatnumber(vatnumber) {
  var regVatnumber = /^[0-9]{9}$/;

  if (regVatnumber.test(vatnumber.value) == false) {
```

```js
function validate_vatnumber(vatnumber) {
  var regVatnumber = /^[0-9]{9}$/;
  
  if (regVatnumber.test(vatnumber) == false) {
    document.getElementById("statusVatnumber").innerHTML = "Vat Number is not valid "
  } 
  else {
    document.getElementById("statusVatnumber").innerHTML = "You have  entered a valid Vat Number!";
  }
}
```

```html
<label>VAT Number :</label>
<br/>
<div class="warn"><span id="statusVatnumber"></span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="vatnumber" class="hiddenId value=" Value="" />
<input type="text" name="vatnumber" id="vatnumber" onkeyup="validate_vatnumber(this.value);" placeholder="VAT Number" title="Please provide a valid company VAT number" />
```

Comment: I have passed the value as you said, but it doesn't seem to make any changes to my problem.  

`onkeyup="validate_vatnumber(this.value);"`  I tries that, or this function `validate_vatnumber(vatnumber) {
  var regVatnumber = /^[0-9]{9}$/;

  if (regVatnumber.test(vatnumber.value) == false) {`

Comment: Working example [here](http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/MaPRJr), with that fix. Can you post your current non-working code?

Comment: Thanks Paul that fixed my problem.

Comment: Paul the regex for validating company registration number, can you please help me with currently i setting with this one `var regRegisternumber =/^[0-9'.\s]{14}[]$/;`. In this case my length is format is suppose to be  1995/088697/21

Comment: You probably want to ask a separate question, and be specific about the format rules -- is it always 4 digits, then `/`, then 6 digits, `/`, and 2 digits? Or something else?

Comment: Yes,it is it always 4 digits, then /, then 6 digits, /, and 2, maybe it met change in future.